# Font-size too big on Android after updating cordova android platform to a newer version than 6.2.3

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I made an App with Ionic V1 long time ago, now everything was fine less the media plugin I had installed, in order to solve a bug i needed to update it and this plugin had as a dependency an cordova android version higher than 6.2.3, as soon as I updated it everything in my device started to look bigger, I adding the meta for scaling:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi, user-scalable=0" />`

But didn't change anything.

I replicated the issue coming back to android cordova 6.2.3, were got fixed(I can't use that version as audio doesn't work for me on that one).

With 6.2.3:
[image: 6.2.3]

With anything higher(I tried 6.3.0, 6.4.0, 7.0.0, 7.1.0):
[image: 7.1.0]